# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND <website> error in NestJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I made a parser to collect the news from other web-sites, and now I'm getting an error in trying to implement this parse-function in my NestJS back-end project. What do I need to do? Maybe the problem is in attempting to connect to other web-sites while using a local server?

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Cron, CronExpression } from '@nestjs/schedule';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { TypeOrmCrudService } from '@nestjsx/crud-typeorm';
import { News } from './entity/news.entity';

@Injectable()
export class NewsService extends TypeOrmCrudService<News> {
    private newsArray: News[];

    constructor(@InjectRepository(News) newsRepository) {
        super(newsRepository);
    }

    fillNewsArray(): void {
        const axios = require('axios');
        const cheerio = require('cheerio');
        let newsArray: News[];
        const parse = async () => {
            const getHTML = async (url) => {
                const { data } = await axios.get(url);
                return cheerio.load(data);
            };

            const selector = await getHTML('https://livennov.ru/news/?PAGEN_2=1');
            selector('div.b-section-item__body').each(async (i, element) => {
                let object: News;
                const title = selector(element).find('h3.b-section-item__title').text();
                const date = selector(element).find('div.b-meta-item').text();
                const url = `https://livennov.ru${selector(element).find('a').attr('href')}`;
                const descURL = await getHTML(`https://livennov.ru${url}`);
                descURL('h2').remove();
                const imgUrl = `https://livennov.ru${descURL('.content-full-width').find('img').attr('data-src')}`;
                const descr = descURL('div.b-news-detail-body').text();
                object.headline = title;
                object.description = descr;
                object.imageUrl = imgUrl;
                object.originalUrl = url;
                object.dateTime = date;
                object.type = 'sports';
                console.log(object)
                newsArray.push(object);
            })
        }
        parse();
    }

    @Cron(CronExpression.EVERY_10_SECONDS)
    async handleCron() {
    }

}
```

Comment: please add the complete error message

Comment: (node:32640) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND livennov.ruhttps
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:67:26)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:32640)

Comment: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)

Comment: @R.LM is that a problem that I want to get a response from the server different from local?

Comment: no there shall be no problem on this side but ENOTFOUND means that the server could not be joined. this could be either server side problem (server not responding) or firewall blocking nest from requestin

Comment: I got one clue, the information from server is being received, but then it doesn't being processed because of the try/catch block absence

Comment: I just don't know how to insert this try/catch in.

Comment: yeah but the try catch isn't in you code it's in the http client code (precisely in `dns.js` code) so check if the url is correct

Comment: @R.LM unfortunately, it is

Comment: does it print the same thing if you request `https://www.google.com` for example ?

Comment: The ENOTFOUND is actually an error that the fully qualified domain name could not be translated using DNS. In other words, the was no DNS found for the domain name being used in the URL.

Comment: sorry for bothering yall, the url was incorrect indeed